# Calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=2y$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=2y$.

When $x = 0$ it seems that the region of interest lies between $y=2$ and $z=4$. If I'm not mistaken I would need to calculate $$\int_D(x^2+y^2-2y) \ dA.$$

Also $D$ seems to be given by $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \le 2y \}$

My question is how can I found the bounds for the integrals? Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would begin by converting to polar coordinates as they are much easier to work with when we have rotational symmetry. We can do this by making the substitution $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y= r\sin\theta$. That would mean $dA = dxdy = rdrd\theta$. (the extra $r$ comes from the jacobian for polar coordinates).

After making this transformation, the region becomes much easier to describe. The paraboloid with equation $z = x^2 + y^2$ can be written as $z = r^2$ and the plane can be written as $z = r\sin\theta$. The new integral becomes $\int (2r\sin\theta - r^2) rdrd\theta$.

Now for the limits. r begins at $0$, but to find its endpoint, we must find the intersection between the plane and the paraboloid. We can easily do this by solving the equation $r^2=2r\sin\theta$ which turns out to be where $r = 2sin\theta$. For the limits on $\theta$, we can see that it is $\pi$ by observation as we are only taking values where $y \ge 0$.

This leaves the final integral to be:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta}(2r^2sin\theta - r^3) drd\theta $$

Answer (score 2):

You found the intersection correctly. Here is a 2D cross section of how it would look when seen from the side on $YZ$ plane. It is bound below by the paraboloid $z = x^2+y^2$ and above by the
plane $z = 2y$,

[image]

From $z = x^2 + y^2, z = 2y,$ you get $x^2 = 2y-y^2 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{2y-y^2}$

So your integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{2y-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}(2y - x^2 - y^2) dx \, dy$

In cylindrical coordinates,

$x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$

So $z = x^2 + y^2 =r ^2 = 2y = 2r \sin \theta \implies r = 2 \sin \theta$

So your integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\theta}(2r\sin \theta - r^2) \, r \, dr \, d\theta$